# V-data-table not registering template code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have seen numerous examples using template inside of v-data-table to allow customizing it. I am trying to build some inline filter functionality with v-menu but I am not even able to get the template to register its changes. Just this simple example adding an icon next to the header does not seem to do anything. Its as if template has no effect and currently no errors are shown in console and the data is loaded as normal.

```
                                <v-data-table :headers="headersResults"
                                          :items="results"
                                          :search="search"
                                          height="inherit"
                                          @@click:row="goToItem">
                                <template v-slot:headers="props">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th v-for="(header,i) in props.headers"
                                            :key="i">
                                            {{ header.text }}
                                            <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
                                            <v-btn icon color="grey lighten-2">
                                                <v-icon class='no-rotate' @@click.stop small color="pink">{{ mdi-magnify }}</v-icon>
                                            </v-btn>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </template>
                            </v-data-table>
```

Even doing a simple example like this does not seem to do anything. I am using the vuetify 2.6.12 via the cdn

```
        <v-data-table :headers="headerset"
                  :items="filteredData"
                  :search="searchTable"
                  height="inherit"
                  @@click:row="goToReview"
                  :loading="loading"
                  loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
                  style="cursor: pointer">
        <template v-slot:item.COLUMNNAME="{ item }">
            <v-chip :color="red"
                    dark>
                {{ item.COLUMNNAME }}
            </v-chip>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Comment: The slot is called `header` not `headers`: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-header

Comment: Even correcting that the issue still persists. No error drawn either. Strange thing is that headers slot must have been from an old example i copied from.

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction?

Comment: I  cannot share the data but it is not in any strange format. It is JSON and the headers and everything seems okay. Any other reasons template would do nothing?